# How to remove part of the webpage in Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am currently working on Jsoup. I already get a Element `content` looks like

```
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
<p>abc</p>
<p>efg</p>
....
```

There are several lines after the efg line, but I wish to remove all line after the efg line, and I wish the result to be a Element (not Elements)

I had tried several way such as

```
content.children().removeAll(content.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(content.children().indexOf(content.select("p:contains(efg)"))));
```

or

```
content.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(content.select("p:contains(efg)")).remove();
```

unfortunatly, none of them works. Does anyone has better solution for this? Thanks for reading this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div> 
 <p>123</p> 
 <p>456</p> 
 <p>789</p> 
 <p>abc</p> 
 <p>efg</p> 
 <p>111</p> 
 <p>222</p> 
 <p>333</p> 
 <p>444</p> 
</div>
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.html")));
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element content = doc.select("div").first();

    Element lastValidElement = content.select("p:contains(efg)").first();
    int lastValidElementIndex = content.children().indexOf(lastValidElement);
    content.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(lastValidElementIndex).remove();
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

---

```
<div> 
 <p>123</p> 
 <p>456</p> 
 <p>789</p> 
 <p>abc</p> 
 <p>efg</p>     
</div>
```